# Can batch script start some programs at specific time? not window scheduled task

Tags: windows, batch-file

Is batch file has the functionary to run a program based on a specific time I enter into the script. The code i attached does not work. Please help.^_^

```
@echo off
For /f "tokens=1-2 delims=/:" %%a in ('time /t') do (set mytime=%%a:%%b)
echo  %mytime%

:check
if %mytime%=="09:30 AM" (
START C:\Desktop\Photoshop.exe
) 

if %mytime%=="11:30 AM" (
START C:\Desktop\itune.exe
) 

else (
timeout /t 36 /nobreak
GOTO :Check
)
```

By the way,I do know Window Task Scheduler can run programs at a specific time. But I just dont wanna use it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `%time%` as it stands like so:

```
@echo off
:check
if "%time%"==" 9:30 AM" (
START "" "C:\Desktop\Photoshop.exe"
) 

if "%time%"=="11:30 AM" (
START "" "C:\Desktop\itune.exe"
) 

timeout /t 3600 /nobreak
GOTO :Check
```

The trouble you have is that your timeout can make the exact time pass by without being checked.

If you use 30 seconds then it should work.

One thing to watch if I am not mistaken, is that the leading character in AM hours is a space.

Comment: It does not work, i guess the format 09:30 AM is not value, can't use == check.

Comment: @hben   If you type `echo "%time%"` then what do you see on the screen? What does `can't use == check` mean?

Comment: If I type echo "%time%" then, nothing show up on the screen. [can't use == check] mean i guess i can't use == as a function to check two thing. @foxidrive

Comment: @aschipfl please take a look

Comment: @hben Something you are doing is not normal.  Open a cmd window and type `echo "%time%"` and see what shows on the screen.  The `==` can certainly be used to compare.

Comment: This won't work as the time is never _exact_ " 09:35 AM" as the time inludes the seconds and miliseconds (e. g. `17:10:05.35`).